# Why I use Alamofire 4.6 and get response to update UI in main thread failed by Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, grand-central-dispatch

Like my question title.
I get response from my API and then I'll update my UI.
But I try to use "DispatchQueue.main" to let in main thread, it also nothing in my view.
What's wrong with me?
And what do I miss to think?
Thanks.

```
class vc: UIViewController {

var headerView: HeaderView = HeaderView() 
var tableView:UITableView = UITableView()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadUI()
    loadLayout()


    API.test.get(success: { data in
            do {

                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
                let root = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)

                print(self.headerView.frame) //(0.0, 0.0, 270.0, 100.0)                

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.loadheaderViewInfo(response: root.response)
                }

            }catch let error as NSError{
                print(error)
            }
        }) { error in
            print(error)
    }
}

func loadUI() {

    tableViewSetting()

    view.addSubview(headerView)
    view.addSubview(tableView)
}

func loadheaderViewInfo(response: Root.Response) {

    headerView.imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_defaultAvatar")
    headerView.nameLabel.text = "response.lastName"

    print(response.lastName) //this have value but don't update UI 
}
}
```

Comment: where you are adding the headerView to any view in the view Hierarchy?

Comment: Sorry, I update that I call in "loadUI()"

Comment: check `Frame` for HeaderView.

Comment: OK, but who is view? another think as check if HeaderView frame is different from CGRect.Zero

Comment: HeaderView have show on view, but the labels in headerView don't show my setting text.

Comment: I update question to print headerview.frame

Comment: @tolerate＿Me_Thx `headerView.nameLabel.text = "response.lastName"`, you must set it to `headerView.nameLabel.text = response.lastName`

Comment: @QuocNguyen ya, It's just that I want to try when I set string text. But It also doesn't show any text.

Comment: do you reload your tableview data?

Comment: @Alper its different view, so I don't roload tableview. I add two views in this viewcontroller.

Comment: I don't know why minus without no reason.